# .NET Core 6 Scaffolding for migration from 3.1 leaves out many-to-many bridging tables

Tags: c#, .net-core

So I am migrating a project from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET Core 6 and would like to scaffold a new context class. Here is the SQL for my db:

```
CREATE TABLE Product 
(
    Product_ID int NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT PK_Products PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    Description varchar(100) NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT UC_Product UNIQUE,
);

CREATE TABLE ProductCategory 
(
    ProductCategory_ID int NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT PK_ProductCategory PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    Description varchar(100) NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT UC_ProductCategory UNIQUE,
);

CREATE TABLE Product_ProductCategory 
(
    Product_ID int NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT FK_ProductProductCategory_Products REFERENCES Product(Product_ID),
    ProductCategory_ID int NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT FK_ProductProductCategory_ProductCategory REFERENCES ProductCategory(ProductCategory_ID),
    CONSTRAINT PK_ProductProductCategory 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Product_ID, ProductCategory_ID)
);
```

Here is the script used to scaffold:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=.;Database=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 
    -OutputDir Models -DataAnnotations 
    -Tables Product, ProductCategory, Product_ProductCategory
```

Using `ProductProductCategory` instead of `Product_ProductCategory` has the same result.

Here is the resulting code in my context class:

```
namespace MyProject.Models
{
    public partial class ProjectContext : DbContext
    {
        public ProjectContext()
        {
        }

        public ProjectContext(DbContextOptions<ProjectContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        //why are there only 2 tables here?
        public virtual DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Product>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.ProductId).ValueGeneratedNever();

                entity.HasMany(d => d.ProductCategories)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Products)
                    .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
                        "ProductProductCategory",
                        l => l.HasOne<ProductCategory>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("ProductCategoryId").HasConstraintName("FK_ProductProductCategory_ProductCategory"),
                        r => r.HasOne<Product>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("ProductId").OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull).HasConstraintName("FK_ProductProductCategory_Products"),
                        j =>
                        {
                            j.HasKey("ProductId", "ProductCategoryId").HasName("PK_ProductProductCategory");

                            j.ToTable("Product_ProductCategory");

                            j.IndexerProperty<int>("ProductId").HasColumnName("Product_ID");

                            j.IndexerProperty<int>("ProductCategoryId").HasColumnName("ProductCategory_ID");
                        });
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<ProductCategory>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.ProductCategoryId).ValueGeneratedNever();
            });

            OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
        }

        partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

The bridging table is simply missing. In my code for the Core 3.1 project, the bridging tables are referenced frequently and their absence causes a lot of errors regarding missing definitions in my context class. It also fails to generate the entity classes.

Is there any reason Core 6 is ignoring these tables entirely? The code does acknowledge the bridging table, but without an actual definition, it cannot be used.

Note that my full code has over 20 such bridging tables. Adding them in manually is not a trivial task. Original entities were also scaffolded in .NET Core 3.1.

Also, the tables are now pluralized. Is there a way to keep them singular? (.NET Core 3.1 Scaffold was singular, causing yet more problems)

Most importantly, though, how do I get the missing bridging tables?

Comment: You can suppress the pluralization with --no-pluralize

Comment: Awesome, one problem down!

Comment: I think if you add a primary key to the bridging tables, then the classes will be created. Please try it out.

Comment: The bridging table in my example has a primary key named 'PK_ProductProductCategory'. For further reference, -NoPluralize is used by the package manager console.

Comment: Ah I thought of a new column as primary key. something like [ID] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL and define it as primary key

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Issue [#22475 Detect simple join tables in reverse engineering and create many-to-many relationships](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/22475) and [#26820 Optionally bring back join tables on scaffold db in EF Core 6](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/26820) were opened for this. Apparently there's no direct way to map join tables, but workarounds are available (and described in the second link).

Comment: The solution described in the second link works! I installed the EF Core Power Tools from here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.EFCorePowerTools and used the Reverse Engineer option plus the joining tables options in the advanced settings. All tables from my DB are now represented using the .NET Core 6 code syntax. Hopefully the next update to Core 6 will include this without needing additional tools.